# Time filter resets to 15min in Kibana dashboard links

Tags: elasticsearch, kibana

I am trying to Visualize the data using the Pie chart and the Heat map, during creation of index I have selected the required time parameter.
Also while drawing the graph I have selected time range as 8 days ,
[image]

After I save the graph , 8 days time frame is reflected in Dashboard view page also,

[image]

But then on next day if I reopen the Kibana Dashboard it gets reset to 15 minutes and no data appears,
Can someone help me figure out the issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When [saving your dashboard](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/kibana/current/create-a-dashboard-of-panels-with-web-server-data.html#_save_the_dashboard), you need to check the box labeled `Store time with dashboard` and it will work the way you expect.

[image]